# Split multiple columns at once, maintain certain elements and split them

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a data frame like this.

> input = read.table('input', header=T, sep='\t')

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
1   E   Z,D 1:115:3:0.0 0/1/2:71:7,5:0.003,0.009
3   ZE  AB,CD,FG    0/3:331:9:0.00588   0/2:235:8:0.04704
```

I split v3 by ","

> v3.input = strsplit(as.character(input$v3), ",")

and replicate the v1 values through data.frame()

> df = data.frame(v1= rep(input$v1, sapply(v3.input, length)), v3= unlist(v3.input))

But I would like to insert the corresponding value of v2 column in the v3 column as first element of the list, then delete the column v2. Moreover, I would like to split the columns v4:v5, by ":", 
retain the first and the third elements and split them by "/" and "," respectively.

The data frame should be as follows

```
v1  v3  v4  v5
1   E   NA  0
1   Z   1,3 1,7
1   D   NA  2,5
3   ZE  0   0
3   AB  NA  NA
3   CD  NA  2,8
3   FG  3,9 NA
```

I tried

> concat.split.multiple(input, split.cols=c("v4", "v5"), seps = ":",
>   direction = "wide")

But, how can I select the first and third elements of the list and split them?

> dput(input)

```
structure(list(v1..v2..v3..v4..v5 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1   E   Z,D 1:115:3:0.0 0/1/2:71:7,5:0.003,0.009", "3   ZE  AB,CD,FG    0/3:331:9:0.00588   0/2:235:8:0.04704"), class = "factor")), .Names = "v1..v2..v3..v4..v5", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Can you give the output of `dput(input)`? That would make sure that anyone is working with exactly what you have to start with.

Comment: This will have to be done in multiple steps. It would be much better if (1) you mention that you are using the "splitstackshape" package, (2) that you provide a smaller example where your input and output match each other.